# Iterate through nested arrays to grab the first object of each array, then the second, etc

Tags: objective-c, arrays, loops

I have nested `Arrays`,

For example:

[[1,2,3,4,5], [A,B,C,D,E], [Z,Y,X,W,V]

I want to iterate through this array and create a new array, that looks like this:

[1,A,Z,2,B,Y,3,C,X,4,D,W,5,E,V]

I was initially thinking of using nested `For` loops, e.g.:

```
   int index = 0;
   int stop = [[arrays objectAtIndex:0] count];
   NSMutableArray* finalArray = [NSMutableArray new];
   while(index < stop)
   {
      for(id array in images)
      {
         [finalArray addObject:[array objectAtIndex:index]];
      }
      index++;
   }
```

What would be the most efficient way of doing this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I don't believe your code will actually generate what you mean (it won't actually compile because `NSArray` doesn't have `addObject:`). What you want is a Zipper:

```
NSArray *Zip(NSArray *arrays) {
  if ([arrays count] == 0) {
    return @[];
  }

  NSMutableArray *result = [NSMutableArray new];

  NSInteger minCount = NSIntegerMax;
  for (NSArray *array in arrays) {
    minCount = MIN(minCount, [array count]);
  }

  for (NSInteger i = 0; i < minCount; i++) {
    for (NSArray *array in arrays) {
      [result addObject:array[i]];
    }
  }

  return result;
}
```

Comment: I like the Min check, good idea.  And I totally forgot to use a for loop instead of a while loop haha.  I was incrementing the index at the end...

Answer (score 1):

Can't comment as I don't have 50 rep, so has to be as an answer!

Have you tried using loops such as

```
Dim i As Integer, j As Integer
For i = 1 To 5
For j = 1 To 3
```

Select Item `i` from array `j`

```
Next j
Next i
```

Comment: Here's an upvote for more rep!
I'm not familiar with Next, which object contains that method?

Comment: You don't need an object for the `Next`, that's part of a loop. I'm not sure about the middle line, which is why I didn't include it in the code, I've not worked with arrays but presumably you can apply this to your method? *also added the dim instructions I missed out*

Comment: Which language are you using?

Comment: Oh fudge - just realised I stepped out of the excel-vba page! I assume there will be a similar method in any language? *hangs head in shame!*